# How to execute Javascript from a JavaFX application in Android

Tags: javascript, android, javafx, rhino, javafxports

I am creating a JavaFX application for Android and using Mozilla Rhino to execute JavaScript code inside my application. The problem is that Mozilla Rhino is very, very slow in Android.

Is it possible to execute 
JavaScript using the included V8 JavaScript engine in Android or use any other JavaScript engine that is faster than Rhino?

Answer (score 0):

How about [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8):

> We developed J2V8 as a high performance engine for our multi-platform mobile toolkit tabris.js and it is a great choice for executing JavaScript on Android devices.

Comment: J2V8 works perfect and is fast in my linux development machine

Comment: The problem is than in Android I get the following exception:

Comment: W/System.err(26698): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: J2V8 native library not loaded.
W/System.err(26698):    at com.eclipsesource.v8.V8.checkNativeLibraryLoaded(V8.java:150)

Comment: I think I use the right dependency when targeting Android: **compile group: 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8', name: 'j2v8_android_armv7l', version: '3.0.2'** . Any clue?

Comment: @adrianromero Check out [this guide](https://gist.github.com/magmastonealex/a9158173828932def9ffb81672d6c578) to see how to build J2V8 on a Linux machine. Otherwise get in touch with the development team via their [issues page](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/issues).